# c# Reading Excel cannot work on server which excel not installed on

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, linq-to-excel, access-data-project

I have writeen a software which some part's process is reading data from excel file. I have used linqtoexcel for this. But ı can't run this app on machine not installed office. And I don't want to install "http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23734"(Access DataBaseEngine). I know , Probles is base on this. So My app will be working on xp machine which stand 24 hours.My apps will run once a day. I am not authorized for install software , only run . I want to embedd AccessDatabaseEngine dll's as referance on VS 2010. Thanks.

Comment: Have you thought about putting the necessary dll's that you need in the GAC on said Server..?

Comment: yes like what you say. I want to build on my computer. Then put apps on xp server :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it's not possible to just include the AccessDatabaseEngine dll's on the server and have LinqToExcel work. The database engine has to be installed on the server.